# CSW extension for geoserver version 2.19.2

Tags: geoserver

We have upgraded our geoserver application to version 2.19.2. Also followed the instructions for installing [Catalog Services for Web (CSW)](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/csw/installing.html). I can see that the CSW is listed as one of the Services but not listed in the Modules tab (as it is supposed to?):
[image]

I have enabled CSW and direct download:
[image]

Then I followed the instruction for [Direct Download](https://docs.geoserver.org/master/en/user/services/csw/directdownload.html).  But in the layers page, under Publishing tab, I don’t see DirectDownload Settings section.

Also to make sure our customized geoserver didn’t impose any conflict or issue, I have downloaded the geoserver web archive version 2.19.2 and added the csw plugin jar files into the WEB-INF/lib. I see the same behavior (Missing CSW from Modules and missing direct download settings from the layers publishing tab)

I would be appreciated if anyone can help me understand and fix this issue.

Answer (score 2):

That means I missed that class when I was [updating](https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS-10067) the module listing code. So your module (and any others that are missing, mostly community modules) will continue to work as expected.

Please submit an issue at https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/jira/software/c/projects/GEOS/issues and we'll make sure it gets fixed the next time we look at that code.

Comment: Thanks Ian for the quick reply. I will submit an issue to the Jira. Do I need to follow up on the issue to make next release will have the fix?

Comment: I have created Jira issue:

https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS-10270

Thanks for your help

Comment: To be sure that it gets fixed you will need to fix it - it may or may not get picked up by another developer